# org.json.JSONException: Value Connected of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: php, mysql, json, android-studio, android-volley

I'm trying to list challenges from an external SQL database.  I am having a big problem.  I am retrieving the data from MySQL ok, but hitting errors on the JSONObject.  I have been trying this for a fair few hours so if someone can point me in the right direction - I have been using this tutorial for reference https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-spinner-example-to-load-json-using-volley/

**PHP FILE - challengesall.php**

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "USER";
$password = "PASS";
$dbname  ="android_api";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";

//$stmt = $dbconn->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM challenges") or die(mysql(mysql_error()));

$stmt = "SELECT * FROM challenges";
$result = $conn->query($stmt);
$results = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            array_push($results,array(  
                'unique_id'=>$row["unique_id"],
                'title'=>$row["title"]
            ));    
      //  echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - unique id: " . $row["unique_id"]. " - title: " . $row["title"]. "<br>";  
    }
    echo json_encode(array('results'=>$results));

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

**Fields**

```
String url = "http://myLocalIPConnectsFine/android_login_api/challengesall.php";
public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "results";
private JSONArray challengeResult;
```

**ChallengeListActivity - Method getData**

```
private void getData() {
        //Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_challenge";
        Log.i("M4: " + TAG + ":- " + STEP, Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName());

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(
                url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.i("M6: " + TAG + ":- " + STEP, Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[3].getMethodName());

                Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
                JSONObject j = null;

                try {
                    //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                    j = new JSONObject(response);  //!!GOES TO CATCH EXCEPTION!!! 

                    //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                    challengeResult = j.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);  //DOES NOT GET HERE!! :((

                    // TODO: Now store the user in SQLite for loop

                    //Calling method getStudents to get the students from the JSON Array
                    getChallenges(challengeResult);
                    // }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) ;
        // Adding request to request queue
        //  AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(strReq);
    }
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
07-25 16:54:09.900 8134-8134/boo.famvsfam D/STEPS:  ChallengeListActivity: Login Response: Connected successfully{"result":[{"unique_id":"57933c641237d4.96974874","title":"23072016"},{"unique_id":"57901472464398.57585757","title":"hayley"},{"unique_id":"5790142623de26.96306456","title":"nbppp"},{"unique_id":"5790133be27ca1.05397869","title":"bopo"},{"unique_id":"57900e98bc4dd2.35778585","title":"howdie"},{"unique_id":"57900dfb7fca74.47168154","title":"BOOO"},{"unique_id":"579006b05dfda0.42529504","title":"BOOO"},{"unique_id":"578f7e139835d2.76955191","title":"ghhg"},{"unique_id":"578f71b8ef5693.01745921","title":"howdie"},{"unique_id":"578f71b50c7407.91547319","title":"howdie"},{"unique_id":"578f4d212bcf41.00048708","title":"heloorout"},{"unique_id":"578f4b794281e1.43679386","title":"heloorout"},{"unique_id":"578ed1338cdfd2.06152669","title":"BOO"},{"unique_id":"578e72b5920bd9.67743323","title":"BOO3"},{"unique_id":"578e7168921b95.27637073","title":"BOO4566677777"},{"unique_id":"578e7161f32df1.06784020","title":"BOO"},{"unique_id":"578e0f7564c5c6.94428032","title":"lalalala"},{"unique_id":"578e0fbb8f95d8.48337399","title":"ghhhh"},{"unique_id":"578f5912ac55f4.71485786","title":"boo"},{"unique_id":"578f54c82c81c5.06156083","title":"jjjj"},{"unique_id":"578f53c251fb73.32146656","title":"ccc"},{"unique_id":"578f53c22ee9e2.44032439","title":"ccc"},{"unique_id":"578f533a759556.38700080","title":"ccc"},{"unique_id":"578f51beafcdd6.40560734","title":"hjjj"},{"unique_id":"578f51b3adc9c6.53224544","title":"hjjj"},{"unique_id":"578d82ebba7e82.61976731","title":"rhtyhrrh"},{"unique_id":"578d71ad826874.17496613","title":"FHGHHH"},{"unique_id":"578d6d659605d7.58107965","title":"BOO5003"},{"unique_id":"578d6d555f0774.18558468","title":"BOO500000"},{"unique_id":"57933ca3e56379.52606857","title":"23072016-1"},{"unique_id":"57933cb6746b58.44233261","title":"23072016-2"},{"unique_id":"579356c1f37c94.92512350","title":"AChallenge"},{"unique_id":"5793571d9238c4.62232112","title":"challenge"},{"unique_id":"5793571da78159.61806596","title":"challenge"},{"unique_id":"57935884e7bcf2.72928133","title":"achallenge"},{"unique_id":"579366336a78a5.36422777","title":"boooo"},{"unique_id":"579366dfe75647.32061097","title":"boooo"},{"unique_id":"57936f03c884b0.46671632","title":"fggggg"},{"unique_id":"57936f9be26a56.60274804","title":"boo"},{"unique_id":"57936fa0adf927.36072785","title":"boo"},{"unique_id":"57936fc695b686.27459827","title":"boo"},{"unique_id":"57937003032435.98039444","title":"boo"},{"unique_id":"579370f3b54f01.71840531","title":"boo"},{"unique_id":"5793785f5d6ff0.67364375","title":"booooo"},{"unique_id":"579379447425d8.12021062","title":"booooo"}]}
07-25 16:54:42.915 8134-8134/boo.famvsfam W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value Connected of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
07-25 16:54:42.916 8134-8134/boo.famvsfam W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
07-25 16:54:42.916 8134-8134/boo.famvsfam W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
07-25 16:54:42.916 8134-8134/boo.famvsfam W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
07-25 16:54:42.916 8134-8134/boo.famvsfam W/System.err:     at boo.famvsfam.controller.ChallengeListActivity$4.onResponse(ChallengeListActivity.java:256)
07-25 16:54:42.916 8134-8134/boo.famvsfam W/System.err:     at boo.famvsfam.controller.ChallengeListActivity$4.onResponse(ChallengeListActivity.java:245)
07-25 16:54:42.916 8134-8134/boo.famvsfam W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:67)
07-25 16:54:42.916 8134-8134/boo.famvsfam W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
07-25 16:54:42.916 8134-8134/boo.famvsfam W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
07-25 16:54:42.916 8134-8134/boo.famvsfam W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
07-25 16:54:42.916 8134-8134/boo.famvsfam W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-25 16:54:42.916 8134-8134/boo.famvsfam W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
07-25 16:54:42.916 8134-8134/boo.famvsfam W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
07-25 16:54:42.916 8134-8134/boo.famvsfam W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-25 16:54:42.916 8134-8134/boo.famvsfam W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
07-25 16:54:42.916 8134-8134/boo.famvsfam W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I do not think I need to post anymore code - the problem seems to be with the `j = new JSONObject(response);`  just after the try. I'm very new JSON but this problem has been around more then a day :(    I think I will be ok after that, but this problem I keep hitting no matter what way I try (and I have tried plenty of tutorials and questions/answers)  Can someone please point out where I am going wrong.  This is the first time i tried JSON.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have any notices, have you tried calling within your browser? Maybe you should set a json type header: `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: I did just run it through my browser and it is fine.

Comment: I have put the header in the php file and there is no difference - but i will keep it there as it seems the done thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When instantiating a [JSONObject](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/json/JSONObject.html) you need to pass the actual string response:

ex: `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("result":[{"unique_id":"57933c641237d4.96974874","title":"23072016"},{"unique_id":"57901472464398.57585757","title":"hayley"}]");`

Given that `response.toString()` gives you the string you should do the following:

```
JSONObject j = new JSONObject(response.toString());
```

P.S: I think you need this if you don't set the content type in your php :

```
<?
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "USER";
$password = "PASS";
$dbname  ="android_api";
....
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your answer! Sorry for the delay in replying I was setting up Android studio on my laptop (took ages).  I did do what you suggested and it didn't work first.  But I was then drawn to the the response string and realised it was picking up the echo confirming connection.  Commenting out that worked.  It works with toString and without, so no doubt I be needing to use toString so will be keeping it.  Json is fiddly...and its put me off echos in php.  Thanks again your example of the string really helped me figure out what was wrong.

Comment: Glad to help, I'm a noob android developer myself and revised an app I worked on. When you have no results maybe return an empty results array.